Distribution of the last element of sequencing of $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$
A non-trivial finite group $G$ of order $n$ is said to be sequenceable if its elements can be arranged in a sequence $(b_1, b_2,...,b_n)$ in such a way that the partial products $(a_1, a_2,...,a_n)$,
where $a_i = b_1b_2 \dots b_i$, are distinct. The sequence $(b_1, b_2,...,b_n)$ is called a sequencing for $G$.
It is known, that $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is sequenceable.
I made a program to count all the sequencing of $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and I've found, that for all $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ except for $0$ and $2^{n-1}$ there is a sequencing, which ends in $g$. Why $0$ and $2^{n-1}$ don't appear is pretty easy: it means that either $b_{n-1}=b_{n}$ or $b_{n-1}=0$, which is not true because, obviously, $b_1=0$. But I don't understand why other elements appear as the last elements of the sequencing at least once. Maybe the idea is to make many sequencing from one known, but I didn't find any means to do that. I'll appreciate any help

I guess there is the mess with $n$, becuase initially it is the order of the group, then you introduce the group $\mathbb Z_{2n}$, and finally speak about its element $2^{n-1}$.
